# I use Lombok project but getter's and setter's don't have JavaDoc

Tags: javadoc, lombok

I use Lombok project but getter's and setter's don't have JavaDoc.

How can i activate this option?

Comment: The point of having JavaDoc on those methods is that they can explain how the field is typically used or link to related fields. Although in most cases the name should be descriptive enough, I've read my share of code where a the purpose of the field was not obvious, or where a setter modifies other behavior. Also, it is a place to annotate the legality of null-values.

Answer (score 8):

There is an inititial implementation in the 0.12.0 release. By default the whole content form the javadoc on the field will be copied to both the getter and the setter. Getters will get the return bit; setters the param bit. Those will be removed from the javadoc on the field. Using sections you can even specify different getter/setter javadoc.

This only works when you delombok the code before generating javadoc, and will probably never work in eclipse.

For the current syntax, please check the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=59)s documentation.

Full Disclosure: I am one of the [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) developers.

Comment: Another question: how can I create final setters safely callable from a constructor with Lombok?